# don't know why im getting error while passing array of objects as props to child component in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I want to pass an array as props to child component and try to create table with the use of that props using react table.

I am getting this error message when passing an array as props to Table component.

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {continent, country, totalcases, criticalcases, activecases, deaths, recovery, newcases, death1mpop, cases1mpop}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

App component:

```
function App() {
  const [totalCases, setTotalCases] = useState({});
  const [countryData, setCountryData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [loadingCountry, setLoadingCountry] = useState(true);

  const getCovidData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const res = await fetch(
      "https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/statistics?country=all",
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "x-rapidapi-host": "covid-193.p.rapidapi.com",
          "x-rapidapi-key":
            "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        },
      }
    );
    const data = await res.json();
    const actualData = data.response[0];
    setTotalCases(actualData);
    setLoading(false);
    // console.log(actualData);
  };

  const getCountriesData = async () => {
    setLoadingCountry(true);
    const res = await fetch("https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/statistics", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "covid-193.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      },
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data.response);
    let requiredData = data.response.map((d) => {
      return {
        continent: d.continent,
        country: d.country,
        totalcases: d.cases.total,
        criticalcases: d.cases.critical,
        activecases: d.cases.active,
        deaths: d.deaths.total,
        recovery: d.cases.recovered,
        newcases: d.cases.new,
        death1mpop: d.deaths["1M_POP"],
        cases1mpop: d.cases["1M_POP"],
      };
    });
    console.log(requiredData);
    setCountryData(requiredData);
    // setCountryData(data.response);
    setLoadingCountry(false);
    console.log(countryData);
    console.log(countryData.length);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getCovidData();
    getCountriesData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Covid Tracker....</h1>
      {loading ? <h1>Loading data</h1> : <Details totalCases={totalCases} />}
      {/* {loadingCountry ? <h1>Loading list</h1>
        :
          <Table countryData={countryData}/>
      } */}
      {/* {countryData !== undefined && <Table countryData={countryData}/>} */}
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: have you checked the `typeof` `requiredData` ? you are returning an `object` after mapping the `data.response`

Comment: as it is array so type of data will be object. when i check it with Array.isArray it returns true

Comment: Could you include your Table component.

Comment: Can you add the response? Looks like it is the parent object you are passing.

Comment: The `Table` component should be the source of the issue then. It's likely trying to render `countryData` as an object instead of a react element.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer - The error message you are getting is absolutely correct. If you read the React Docs, Your JSX compiles to React.createElement(component, props, ...children). And yes objects cannot be children. Ref - https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx

Since I don't have your sample data, I am assuming your data might be like this:

```
<Test arr={[{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }]} />
```

I am creating a small component to render this data:

```
import React from "react"

function Test(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.arr.map((x, index) => {
        console.log(index, x);
        // return <h1 key={index}>{x}</h1>;
        return <h1 key={index}>{Object.keys(x).map((y) => x[y])}</h1>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

If I place object in JSX, it will throw an error (Commented Code).
Also please check the Table component (if its 3rd party lib), in which format it is expecting the data. If it's yours then you have to iterate over object using `Object.entries()` or `Object.keys()`, `Object.values()` to display data

Hope this answers your question. Please upvote if you find it helpful.